# mysql query with main & sub access id

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this

```
ownerlisting_access_id   property_id    mainaccess_id   subaccess_id access_value
 62                      2              35      41           Yes
 64                      2              35      36           Yes
123                      4              35      41       Yes
125                      4              35      36       Yes
306                      7              35      41       Yes
307                      7              35      42       Yes
308                      7              35      36       Yes
```

I need to get the property_id which is serving the subaccess_id with 41 & 42 & 36. 
I need to get the property_id as 7.

Comment: Sounds fun. Good luck! (it will probably help if you try something yourself first, then come back and let us know what you tried and why it didn't work)

Comment: SELECT property_id FROM owner_property_accessibility WHERE subaccess_id = '41' AND subaccess_id = '42' AND  subaccess_id = '36' GROUP BY property_id

Comment: Delete that comment and put it in your question.

Comment: @mikejohnvino If `subaccess_id = '41'` then it **can not** also be equal to `'42'`. So that query in your comment will not return anything :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT property_id FROM t
WHERE subaccess_id IN (41, 42, 36)
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subaccess_id) = 3
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ddf5/1).

Bear in mind that you should match the amount of elements in the `IN` clause with the number in the `HAVING` clause. Also note that if you can not have the same `subaccess_id` more than once for a given `property_id` then you can remove the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: No need to say thanks. That's what accepting answers is there for :)